# Head First Java Puzzle4 (Chapter 4, pg 91) Explanation

Tags: java

Below is the solution to, and output of,the subject puzzle, and I'm having trouble understanding how it works.

```
public class Puzzle4 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  Puzzle4b[] obs = new Puzzle4b[6];
  int y = 1;
  int x = 0;
  int result = 0;

    while (x<6) {
      obs[x] = new Puzzle4b();
      obs[x].ivar = y;
      y = y*10;
      x = x+1;
    }

    x = 6;

    while (x>0) {
      x = x-1;
      result = result + obs[x].doStuff(x);
    }

    System.out.println("result " + result);
   }
  }

  class Puzzle4b {

  int ivar;

  public int doStuff(int factor) {

    if (ivar>100) {
      return ivar*factor;
      } else {
      return ivar*(5-factor);
    }
   }
  }
```

Output:

```
result 543345
```

From my understanding, the first While loop will run through 6 times (from x==0 to x==5).  The y variable, and in turn 'ivar', will have a value of 1,000,000 (I think this is where I'm going wrong, but I'll continue in hopes of being corrected).

The second While loop is a bit confusing to me.  It'll run through 6 times, with the second line of the loop passing the 'x' values to the doStuff method for it to return a value.  The numbers I'm coming up with for the result don't match the actual result.

Any help here would be appreciated.  Please let me know if I'm thinking about it the wrong way.  If someone wants to reformat my code to align more closely with industry standards, it would be great to learn good habits from the start!

Comment: It would help if you explained the puzzle first.

Comment: Did you step through the code one line at a time in your debugger? If not, that is the place to start.  Then, when you identify the exact place where it doesn't behave the way you expect, if you still have a question, [edit] your post and include details on what you don't understand.

Comment: 1.  It's just an exercise that asks the reader to fill in some blanks with code from a pool of possibilities.  Not really a puzzle.

Comment: 2.  Looks like I'll need a debugger!  Will follow up if I'm still confused after doing what you suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

this piece of code `

```
 obs[x].ivar = y;
      y = y*10;
```

will cause first ivar = y = 1  then multiple y 
so it'll be {1 - 10 - 100 - 1,000 - 10,000 - 100,000}

the second loop x will be   { 5 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 1 , 0 }
so it'll start like this    result = result+obs[5].doStuff[5];

i guess all the misunderstanding that x in element 1 will equal y in element 5 
and x in element 2 will equal y in element 4 and so on " because x is incrementing   and y is decrementing

so it will go like this

```
  (ivar > 100 ) 
   ivar * (5-factor)
  x[3] * y[2] = 1000 * (5-2) = 3000
  x[4] * y[1] = 10000 * (5-1) = 40000
  x[5] * y [0] = 100000 * (5-0) = 500000

then (ivar < 100)
  ivar * factor 
 x[1] * y [5] = 1 * 5 = 5 
 x[2] * y [4] = 10 * 4 = 40
 x[3] * y [3] = 100 * 3= 300
```

then if you add all the numbers together you'll have your output

Answer (score 1):

In the second while loop,
 while(x>0) will give 543340
Instead While (x>=0) should give the required output
If I'm not wrong

Answer (score 0):

For me an easy way to break this down is stepping through and seeing exactly where the values are coming from.  I've done this below and commented it into the code.

```
public class Puzzle4 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  Puzzle4b[] obs = new Puzzle4b[6];
  int y = 1;
  int x = 0;
  int result = 0;

    // let's break out of the loops
    obs[0] = new Puzzle4b();
    obs[0].ivar = 1;
    obs[1] = new Puzzle4b();
    obs[1].ivar = 10;
    obs[2] = new Puzzle4b();
    obs[2].ivar = 100;
    obs[3] = new Puzzle4b();
    obs[3].ivar = 1000;
    obs[4] = new Puzzle4b();
    obs[4].ivar = 10000;
    obs[5] = new Puzzle4b();
    obs[5].ivar = 100000;
    // ivar's = 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000

    result = result + obs[5].doStuff(5); // 0 + (5 * 100000)
    result = result + obs[4].doStuff(4); // 500000 + (4 * 10000)
    result = result + obs[3].doStuff(3); // 540000 + (3 * 1000)
    result = result + obs[2].doStuff(2); // 543000 + ((5 - 2) * 100)
    result = result + obs[1].doStuff(1); // 543300 + ((5-1) * 10)
    result = result + obs[0].doStuff(0); // 543340 + ((5-0) * 1)
    // result = 543345
    }

    System.out.println("result " + result);
   }
  }

  class Puzzle4b {

  int ivar;

  public int doStuff(int factor) {

    if (ivar>100) {
      return ivar*factor;
      } else {
      return ivar*(5-factor);
    }
   }
  }
```

Hope this has helped you understand the example.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to understand what each loop does.
1st one is nothing but just assigning values to ivar variable of each array object. You do it with "x" value as index.

2nd one you still get indices from what "x" variable currently is. And then you need to remember what ivar value is for exactly this index. With that in mind you will be able to understand what condition of doStuff method is true and what expression you should use respectively.

Also, you have to remember of what value "result" variable get on each loop iteration. Like 1st iteration result = 500 000. then 2nd one will be result = 500 000 + doStuff.

And last but not least, not without reason the book calls you to do exercises on paper. It leads to a lot of writing but also to understanding what code does on each and every line.